# Improving the performance of a query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hiveql

My background is Oracle but we've moved to Hadoop on AWS and I'm accessing our logs using Hive SQL.  I've been asked to return a report where the number of high severity errors on the system of any given type exceeds 9 in any rolling period of 30 days (9 but I use 2 in the example to keep the example data volumes down) by uptime. I've written code to do this but I don't really understand performance tuning in Hive.  A lot of the stuff I learned in Oracle doesn't seem applicable.

Can this be improved?

Data is roughly

```
CREATE TABLE LOG_TABLE
(SYSTEM_ID  VARCHAR(1),
 EVENT_TYPE VARCHAR(2),
 EVENT_ID   VARCHAR(3),
 EVENT_DATE DATE,
 UPTIME INT);

INSERT INOT LOG_TABLE
VALUES
('1','A1','138','2018-10-29',34),
('1','A2','146','2018-11-13',49),
('1','A3','140','2018-11-02',38),
('1','B1','130','2018-10-13',18),
('1','B1','150','2018-11-19',55),
('1','B2','137','2018-10-27',32),
('2','A1','128','2018-10-11',59),
('2','A1','131','2018-10-16',64),
('2','A1','136','2018-10-25',73),
('2','A2','139','2018-10-31',79),
('2','A2','145','2018-11-11',90),
('2','A2','147','2018-11-14',93),
('2','A3','135','2018-10-24',72),
('2','B1','124','2018-10-03',51),
('2','B1','133','2018-10-19',67),
('2','B2','134','2018-10-22',70),
('2','B2','142','2018-11-06',85),
('2','B2','148','2018-11-15',94),
('2','B2','149','2018-11-17',96),
('3','A2','127','2018-10-10',122),
('3','A3','123','2018-10-01',113),
('3','A3','125','2018-10-06',118),
('3','A3','126','2018-10-07',119),
('3','A3','141','2018-11-05',148),
('3','A3','144','2018-11-10',153),
('3','B1','132','2018-10-18',130),
('3','B1','143','2018-11-08',151),
('3','B2','129','2018-10-12',124);
```

and code that works is as follows.  I do a self join on the log table to return all the records with the gap between them and include those with a gap of 30 days or less.  I then select those where there are more than 2 events into a second cte and from these I count distinct event types and event ids by system and uptime range

```
WITH EVENTGAP AS  
(SELECT T1.EVENT_TYPE,
       T1.SYSTEM_ID,
       T1.EVENT_ID,
       T2.EVENT_ID AS EVENT_ID2,
       T1.EVENT_DATE,
       T2.EVENT_DATE AS EVENT_DATE2,
       T1.UPTIME,
       DATEDIFF(T2.EVENT_DATE,T1.EVENT_DATE) AS EVENT_GAP
FROM LOG_TABLE T1
  INNER JOIN LOG_TABLE T2
  ON (T1.EVENT_TYPE=T2.EVENT_TYPE
  AND T1.SYSTEM_ID=T2.SYSTEM_ID)
WHERE DATEDIFF(T2.EVENT_DATE,T1.EVENT_DATE) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
  AND T1.UPTIME BETWEEN 0 AND 299
  AND T2.UPTIME BETWEEN 0 AND 330),

 EVENTCOUNT
AS (SELECT EVENT_TYPE,
       SYSTEM_ID,
       EVENT_ID,
       EVENT_DATE,
       COUNT(1)
FROM EVENTGAP
GROUP BY EVENT_TYPE,
       SYSTEM_ID,
       EVENT_ID,
       EVENT_DATE
HAVING COUNT(1)>2)

SELECT EVENTGAP.SYSTEM_ID, 
       CASE WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 0 THEN '0-49'
        WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 1 THEN '50-99'
        WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 2 THEN '100-149'
        WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 3 THEN '150-199'
        WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 4 THEN '200-249'
        WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 5 THEN '250-299' END AS UPTIME_BAND,
       COUNT(DISTINCT EVENTGAP.EVENT_ID2) AS EVENT_COUNT, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT EVENTGAP.EVENT_TYPE) AS TYPE_COUNT 
FROM EVENTGAP
WHERE EVENTGAP.EVENT_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT EVENTCOUNT.EVENT_ID FROM EVENTCOUNT)
GROUP BY EVENTGAP.SYSTEM_ID,
      CASE WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 0 THEN '0-49'
        WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 1 THEN '50-99'
        WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 2 THEN '100-149'
        WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 3 THEN '150-199'
        WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 4 THEN '200-249'
        WHEN FLOOR(UPTIME/50) = 5 THEN '250-299' END
```

This gives the following result, which should be unique counts of event ids and event types that have 3 or more events falling in any rolling 30 day period.  Some events may be in more than one period but will only be counted once.

```
EVENTGAP.SYSTEM_ID  UPTIME_BAND EVENT_COUNT TYPE_COUNT
2   50-99   10  3
3   100-149 4   1
```

Comment: Any indexes on the table? And are you able to add them? Also, not sure about Hive, but in SQL Server, using a CTE multiple times results in multiple hits to the data layer. So your query may be performing more reads than you expect.

Comment: This is part of the bit I don't get, the SQL is a front end to a map reduce against the back end data so indexes aren't a thing unless I have misunderstood it.

Comment: Again, I'm trying to defer to hive people here, but I see numerous guides on the googles of how to create indexes in hive. I assume hive is materializing the hadoop files into memory somehow in the background (possibly via MapReduce as you noted). Temporary tables can certainly be indexed in standard SQL. So it seems perfectly possible to my mind.

Comment: I will have to do some more reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both Hive and Oracle, you would want to do this using window functions, using a window frame clause.  The exact logic is different in the two databases.

In Hive you can use `range between` if you convert `event_date` to a number.  A typical method is to subtract a fixed value from it.  Another method is to use unix timestamps:

```
select lt.*
from (select lt.*,
             count(*) over (partition by event_type
                            order by unix_timestamp(event_date)
                            range between 60*24*24*30 preceding and current row
                           ) as rolling_count
      from log_table lt
     ) lt
where rolling_count >= 2  -- or 9
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a preceding missing in the range statement?